# CSS: elements are not taking a fixed height on flexbox layout

Tags: css, flexbox

I am having troubles with making elements `sections` to take a size and are ordered using `flexbox column`, my goal is to make one element to take the rest of the space and all the sibling elements take that same height but what happens is that these `sections` are not taking that height for some reason and so their height is somewhat null, the fiddle code is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wk20zwrb/5/)

HTML code is like this:

```
<body class="flexed-column">
    <header class="default-primary-color flexed-row">
        <div id="header-text" class="text-primary-color">
            Personal Site
        </div>
    </header>

    <content class="flexed-row flex-grow">
        <div id="main" class="flexed-column flex-grow">
            <section id="section-home" class="flexed-column">
                <img id="user-thumbnail" src="https://pingendo.github.io/pingendo-bootstrap/assets/user_placeholder.png">

                <h2 id="user-name" class="primary-text-color">Name <span id="user-nickname" class="secondary-text-color">(Nickname)</span></h2>

                <h3 id="user-title">Title</h3>
            </section>

            <section id="section-biography">
                <h1 class="section-title primary-text-color" data-msg="biography">{biography}</h1>
            </section>

            <section id="section-projects" class="flexed-column">
                <h1 class="section-title primary-text-color" data-msg="projects">{projects}</h1>

                <div class="flexed-row flex-grow section-content wrapper">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-media">
                            <img src="https://placehold.it/320x180">
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-title">
                            <h3 class="card-title-text primary-text-color">Title here</h3>
                            <p class="card-title-sub-text secondary-text-color">Sub-title here</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </content>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
body{
    margin: 0;
}

header{
    height: 60px;
    justify-content: space-between;
    z-index: 100;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 1px #CCC;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 1px #CCC;
}
header > #header-text{
    margin: 18px;
    font-size: 20px;    
}

content{
    z-index: 90;
}

.hidden{
    display: none;
}

#main{
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
#main > section{
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#main > section h1.section-title{
    margin: 15px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
#main > section .section-content{
    margin: 0 15px;
}

section#section-home > #user-thumbnail{
    height: 160px;
    width: 160px;
    margin: auto auto 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
section#section-home > #user-name{
    margin: 20px auto;
}
#user-name > #user-nickname{
    font-size: 16px;
    font-style: italic;
}
section#section-home > #user-email,
section#section-home > #user-available{
    margin: 10px auto;
}
section#section-home > #user-title{
    margin: 20px auto auto;
}

.flexed-row{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
.flexed-column{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.flexed-row.wrapper,
.flexed-column.wrapper{
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-content: space-around;
    align-items: baseline;
}
.flexed-row > .flex-grow,
.flexed-column > .flex-grow{
    flex: 1;
}
.centered{
    margin: auto;
}
.centered-row{
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.card{
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0px #CCC;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0px #CCC;

    transition: all .2s;
}
.card:hover{
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 8px 0px #CCC;
    box-shadow: 0 6px 8px 0px #CCC;
}
.card > .card-media{
    height: 180px;
    width: 320px;
}
.card > .card-title{
    padding: 16px;
}
.card > .card-title > .card-title-text{
    margin: 0;
}
.card > .card-title > .card-title-sub-text{
    margin: 8px 0 0;
}
```

i am still learning how to properly use `CSS`, i just wish each section to take 100% of the remaining height space so when scrolled it could be possible to just see one entire section instead of 2 or 3

**Note:** I don't want the header to be on position fixed, the sibling element which is `#main` is the only element i want to be scrolled on overflow

Comment: like this? https://jsfiddle.net/wk20zwrb/6/

Comment: @MichaelCoker nice.. is it possible to make the header to not be scrollable? like everything should be scrollable but the header

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wk20zwrb/7/

Comment: @MichaelCoker that is close to what i was trying to achieve, i did not want to make the header to be positioned on fixed, just the #main to be scrolled

Comment: Please edit your question so that your end goal is clearly stated.

Comment: @MichaelCoker i just edited the question

Comment: like this? https://jsfiddle.net/wk20zwrb/10/

Answer (score 0):

after hours of struggling with tests, i have finally found a way to make `#main` to be the only scrollable element by adding `height: calc(100vh - 60px)`, 60px is the height the header takes so all the sections takes the `#main` height